# Docker container EXIT IP on system with multiple ip aliases and gateways, iptables iproute2

Tags: networking, docker, alias, iptables

I have a gentoo system with multiple ip addressess and default gateways on same interface. I have a docker container as mail server.

But I found, that mail server is not sending mail from the ip, that was passed with `-p` command, but from first ip in interface. That way, mail is not delivering as there is no PTR/SPF records about this ip.

How to specify an exit IP address for docker container?
I have configured all with iproute2.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it using:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source xx.xx.xx.xx
```

where `10.0.0.0/24` is my docker network and `xx.xx.xx.xx` is the exit ip address